# Gurobi/python formulating a constraint

Tags: python, constraints, gurobi

I have a parameter called f which has three values. I need to formulate a constraint with the right-hand side set to f. the f and constraints can be exemplified as follows:

f = 1  if i in P

f = -1 if i in D

f = O  otherwise

Xi + Yi = f  for i in P+D

I have formulated the constraint in Gurobi as next? is there another way instead of splitting the constraint into two parts?

```
m.addConstrs((quicksum(x[i])+quicksum(y[i]) == 1 for i in P)
m.addConstrs((quicksum(x[i])+quicksum(y[i]) == -1 for i in D)
```

Comment: I don't see an issue with having two `addConstrs` calls. Merging this into one line is likely making the code harder to read.

Comment: Your idea of writing separate constraints for the cases of -1,0 and 1 seems best. However, your math doesn't look like your code - you should eliminate the (quick)sum and use a for-all on the constraints.

Comment: Okay great.......I don't care about the mathematics right now....it is just a mamic of the real constraint